# Why does "half" not follow the pattern of ordinal numbers across languages?

Tags: etymology, lexical-semantics

The cardinal "a half" is unrelated to "two", whereas "a third", "a quarter" (and certainly "a fourth"), etc. are related to "three", "four", etc. This seems to be true in other languages, too, in various language families:

- Portuguese *metade* but *quarto*;
- German *Hälfte* but *Viertel*;
- Scottish *leth* but *cairteal*;
- Hebrew *חצי* but *רבע*;
- Hungarian *fél* but *negyed*.

Two questions:

- How universal is this?
- If it is pretty universal, then why? Why are words meaning "a half" different from the rest?

Comment: Interesting question! My guess is that this irregularity is an instance of suppletion, caused, as usual, by the high frequency of use. The word for "half" is more frequently used than the words for the other fractions numbers.

Comment: Why didn't you make this an answer?

Comment: I'd think you'd find that words meaning "half" is a lot older than the names the other fractions (which are usually derived from the fraction). I'd guess that "half" in different languages comes from "a part of" or "divided" as oposed to "whole"; and the meaning 1/2 is fairly modern.

Comment: In Russian, 1/2 can be "half" (polovina) or "one.F 2th" (odna vtoraja). I think the form "odna vtoraja" is actually preferred in math.

Comment: Is "half" a word included in Swadesh lists? Is it known how freely it is subject to borrowing/replacement? Does it correlate pretty highly between related languages?

Comment: Good question, it is even impossible to say "one second" as an alternative.

Comment: Note that, in Japanese, there are two different words that denote "a half". One--"hambun"--comes from the Chinese word for "half" (itself not related to the notion of "two"), and the other--"nibun no ichi"--literally means "one of two parts" and falls into the pattern for expressing one third, one fourth, etc. (i.e. it would be like saying "one second" in English).

Comment: @hoppietrail - half isn't on the Swadesh list and is often hard to elicit.

Comment: This really doesn't answer your question at all, but it's not the case everywhere that "quarter" and the like are obviously related to their cardinal counterparts crosslinguistically. As you mention, "fourth" has a much more obvious relation than "quarter". But, South Asian languages usually have distinct words for 3/4, 1 1/2, and 2 1/2 (poune, deR, and aRai in Bangla), none of which seem to be related to any of the plausible cognates (ek do tin car `one, two, three, four')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I suspected, this is indeed a case of **suppletion**, a term defined by [A Glossary of Historical Linguistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0874808936) as

> The use of two or more originally unconnected
>   forms (roots, stems) in the inflection of a single lexical
>   item, for example, *go*/*went*, where originally *went* was
>   not part of the tenses of ‘to go’ but rather was the past
>   tense of *wend*, which was taken over as the past of ‘to
>   go’ and incorporated into its inflectional paradigm.

Examining your examples:

- Portuguese *metade* is cognate to *meio*, from Latin *medius*, ultimately from PIE **medʰyo-* (‘between’). Analogously for other Romance languages.
- German *Hälfte* comes from Proto-Germanic **halbaz*, which is connected with the Indo-European root **(s)kel-* ('to split'). Analogously for other Germanic languages.
- Scottish *leth* comes from Old Irish *leth*, (‘side’). Analogously for other Goidelic languages.
- Hebrew *חצי* is derived from the root *חצה* ('to divide').
- Hungarian *fél* comes from Proto-Uralic *pälä* ('side'). Analogously for other Uralic languages.

Accorging to [Fisiak](http://books.google.com/books?id=76UUIcCqMYkC), this is the same process that caused the irregularity *one* → *first*, *two* → *second* in several languages. Since the word for *half* (as the words for *first*, *second* and *third*) is much more frequently used than the words for other fractions, it tends to maintain its irregularity over time. Another source of this irregularity is that children do not learn to count as *one* → *first*, *two* → *second*, etc. Instead, they learn the ordinal and cardinal sequences separately. This is probably what happens to the fraction numbers as well, which constitutes another barrier to regularization.