# Words for fractions

Tags: comparative-linguistics, lexicon, numbers

While in English we have a "quarter" and a " half" as two words which denote fractions, in Hindi we have separate words for half ('Aadha'), Quarter ('Sava'), three-quarters ('Pauna'), One and a half ('Dedh') and two and a half ('Dhai').

> How may separate words do we have for fractions in other languages?

Comment: _Quarter_ and _half_ are also coinage words, as are _dime, nickel,_ and _penny_ in the US, and _farthing, ha'penny,_ and no doubt others as well in the U.K. Familiar and frequently used fractions will often develop their own terms, and fractions are frequent in trade. Then there is the metric system and scientific nomenclature as a whole.

Comment: See [this related question](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/918/why-does-half-not-follow-the-pattern-of-ordinal-numbers-across-languages).

Comment: @OtavioMacedo copied a comment from the post referred : "This really doesn't answer your question at all, but it's not the case everywhere that "quarter" and the like are obviously related to their cardinal counterparts crosslinguistically. As you mention, "fourth" has a much more obvious relation than "quarter". But, South Asian languages usually have distinct words for 3/4, 1 1/2, and 2 1/2 (poune, deR, and aRai in Bangla), none of which seem to be related to any of the plausible cognates (ek do tin car `one, two, three, four') – dustinalfonso ". The point in question.

Comment: @jlawler " Familiar and frequently used fractions will often develop their own terms" ... so it would be interesting to compare languages on this aspect.

Comment: @jlawler Could add _bit_ to the list of coinage words related to fractions. This is from "pieces of eight" of Spanish dollars.

Comment: What about *"cent"* as "one hundredth"? Also, many Slavonic languages use ordinal numbers to denote corresponding fractions, e.g., "seventh" in meaning of "[one] seventh [part]". We also have 1½ as single word.

Comment: These are not separate roots such as those I describe above