# Terminology for the words used to represent fractions in a language? Examples where it is different to the words used for cardinal or ordinal numbers?

Tags: terminology, word-classes, mathematical-language

While in English Romance languages and Germanic languages, the rendering of fractions usually corresponds to that of the ordinal numbers, i.e a fifth, and a sixth, a seventh, etc. ; it seems to me that conceptually, they are are a different entity.

To highlight this, in Germanic and Romance languages there seem to be a few exceptions peppered in the lower numbers: English ½= a half  2nd = second , ¼= quarter vs. 4th= fourth.  Spanish: ⅓ = um tercio  3º = tercero .

All the texts I've read refer to the set of "half, third, quarter, fifth..." etc. as the "ordinal numbers" of a language.  However, it seems to me they are a separate conceptual entity (innately; but also as demonstrated by the presence of the exceptions).

Is there a linguistic term for the set of these words in a language?

Are there any examples of languages which have a set of words (more than 2 or 3) for fractions that are different from both the ordinal number (e.g. "one third") or the cardinal (e.g. "one over three") numbers.

Comment: To helpful editors, http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/918/why-does-half-not-follow-the-pattern-of-ordinal-numbers-across-languages is related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: What is the referent of "these words" -- fractions? Fractions without etymological relation to their inverse integers? How does pronunciation relate to your question? Since you know of the word "half", what does the question "Does it *always* conform to to ordinal number" mean (the answer is "Obviously, no". E,g, what does "conform" mean, or "always"?

Comment: I have edited my question based on your comments, I hope it's clearer now.  My academic background is not in linguistics, and I was misusing the word pronunciation, or at least using it in a non technical sense. The meaning I was trying to convey was "the morpheme for the concept of a fraction" rather than "what phonemes are used to render this".

Comment: *All the texts I've read refer to the set of "half, third, quarter, fifth..." etc. as the "ordinal numbers" of a language.* I doubt this is true, or if so all these texts are incorrect -- as you rightly point out, "ordinal numbers" refers to the set "first, second, third...", not to fractions.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't encountered a special linguistic term for the denominator in fractions, and I'd be surprised at any linguistic work saying that "third, fourth, fifth" as used in fractions *is* an ordinal number -- it's the same (in form -- or pronunciation) as an ordinal number, but what a number "is" also involves its meaning.

In Swahili, there are special lexical items (like "half") for some fractions, from 1/2 to 1/6 (whereafter a general construction is used "__ part of N"). The lexicalized denominators (nusu, theluthi, robo, humusi, sudusu) are unrelated to the terms for cardinal numbers 2-6 (mbiri, tatu, nne, tano, sita). Ordinal numbers in Swahili are a regular grammatical transformation of cardinal numbers, except "first" is rendered as "beginning".

Comment: _Theluthi, robo, humusi, sudusu_ are obviously borrowings from Arabic.

Comment: *Nusu* is also obviously from Arabic نصف. Beats me what happened to the *f*.

Comment: @user6726. نص is common in Arabic dialects.

Comment: The Swahili cardinal numbers from 6 to 9 are also borrowed from Arabic. So it is wrong to say that they are "unrelated" to corresponding fractions, which are also taken from Arabic.

Comment: If you'd care to explain how *sudus* relates to *sitta* in Arabic, that would be enlightening. As for the rest of those numerals, I cannot imagine how *nusu* would relate to *mbili* (oops, I have an r/l issue in Swahili), or how *robo* would relate to *nne*. Maybe you didn't understand my sentence?

Comment: Arabic sitt, sitta “six”, sādis “sixth (ordinal)”, suds “sixth (fraction)" all derive from Semitic *s1idϑ, with various kinds of assimilation.

Answer (score 1):

In Slavic languages the cardinals (единъ (1), дъва (2), трьѥ (3), пѧть (5), съто (100)... /masc (fem and neut are also possible)/); the fractions (половина (1/2), третина (1/3), пѧтина (1/5), сътотна (1/100)  /only fem/) and the ordinals (пьрви (1th), вътори (2th), трети (3th), пѧти (5th), сътотни (100th) /masc (fem and neut are also possible)/) are all different... The fractions are sometimes called *дроби* = "partive" ie "fractional" numbers (I can't translate it exactly in English).

Answer (score 1):

There are no general terms that I know of, other than "fractions" I suspect this is the sort of language trading peoples would invent. Who knows what metaphorical pathways there are for their creation. I doubt Pirahã has such language. With time these things become lexicalized and people forget the etymologies and histories.

In "European" languages I guess you expect them to be regular (and probably "feminine") as they are probably participles, or as Douglas Harper (etymonline.com) says quoting "Watkins:"

> marking the accomplishment of the notion of the base

...That it is a result adjective or verb-thingy is not surprizing. In Turkish, for example, to split is "ikiye bölmek" to cut (in)to two. But also, you expect things below ten to be a bit irregular, due to (over)use. Also, arbitrary historical things related to cultural and religious metaphor.

English has another from of fractional speak:  "one in four" "ten in one-hundred" And Spanish "uno de cada cuantro," "diez de cada cien" But this is not limited to the badly inbred European languages; Turkish has: "Dörtte bir",(one in four) "Yüzde on" (ten in 100) all marked with the locative.

Turkish also has two lexicalized words like "half" of English or "mitad" of Spanish:  Yarım (half) & Çeyrek (quarter). "Yarım" is a verbal element from another 'to cut' verb (think something like: cutted)- a result noun.  "Çeyrek" comes from Farsi and is composed of familiar Indo-European elements چار يك  VERY literally: four in one.

The other form in Turkish is verbal 1/4 bir bölü dört approx.: '1 divided 4'. The noun "bölü" is one of the modern Turkish derivatives of "bölmek" which I mentioned before. In Ottoman Turkish they used the Arabic تقسيم Taksim

Turkish also has regular (in form) ordinal suffix (In Modern Turkish almost everything can be an ending), but I do not know its history and it is NOT used in fractions (I learned this the natural way by making a fool of myself early in my learning experience).

In short, the ways and language used to describe a *fraction of a whole changes* from langauge to language as can be seen from this completelt unrepresentative of the 7000-9000 human languages around today. ....Three seven-thousands at best.

Comment: I have now had the experience of learning a bit of Tagalog in Manila. Sure enough, in Tagalog (a super trade language) has the structure numerator-denominator. 

So a fifth is literally isapito(ng) which means one five (in one word).

Answer (score 0):

In Arabic the ordinal numbers (third, fourth, fifth…) are thālith, rābiʽ, khāmis etc. The corresponding fractions are formed form the same roots, but a different pattern: thulth, rubʽ, khums etc. Similarly in other Semitic languages.